# In Eclipse, can you have different sets of open files for different perspectives?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, perspective, stm32cubeide

I'm using STM32CubeIDE, an eclipse-based IDE for embedded development. When I start a debug session it switches to the Debug perspective. During the debug session, various extra source files typically get opened in the editor when I pause execution at random times and the currently executed line is deep within some vendor library file. Then I end the debug session and it switches to the normal C/C++ perspective, however all those uninteresting library files that were opened in the debug session are left open. This is annoying, I find myself routinely de-cluttering the editor window by manually closing 10 to 20 uninteresting files that were opened by the IDE during debugging.

So, is there a way for perspectives to preserve their own set of open files (possibly using an add-on extension)? or perhaps you could think of another Eclipse feature that will help with this annoyance? I'm sure I'm not the only one who finds this inconvenient.

Thanks!

Comment: No, perspectives can't control the files that are open. Note that there is a "Close Tabs to Right" on the context menu of an editor tab which can close lots of files at once.

Comment: It might be a bit of a hack, but you might be able to use Mylyn Tasks for this. Define two tasks, one your "Editing Task" and the other your "Debugging Task". Do your editing in the "Editing Task". Just before you run the application, switch to the "Debugging Task". Run your tests, and when you're done, switch back to the "Editing Task".

Comment: @DavidM.Karr interesting, I'll take a look. Not as seamless as I would hope but definitely sounds like an improvement on the current situation.